# What type of AES encryption is this?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, aes

I am supposed to do a text encryption on this project I am working on, I came across this code which works perfectly fine, but I don't know what type of encryption this is, can anyone help me answering what type of encryption it is ?

[AES Encryption and Decryption in VB.NET](https://gist.github.com/ShaneGowland/5973974) was the title of the project I got the code from. If it is `AES`, is it `AES-128`, `AES-192` or `AES-256`?

```
Public Function AES_Encrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String

    Try
        Dim hash(31) As Byte
        Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
        AES.Key = hash
        AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return encrypted
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return input 'If encryption fails, return the unaltered input.
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AES_Encrypt(TextBox1.Text, ")l|_^WR]!u;j$5:(vuU6K5j+9%{U<:FC")
    Label1.Text = encrypted
End Sub
```

Comment: I removed the completely irrelevant "C++" tag. Please don't spam language tags.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Looks like 256 since your key size is 32x8 bits (=256 bits). Also, consider switching to another cipher mode, ECB is [**not recommended**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode?view=netframework-4.8).